# How to update Activity UI based on ListView item selection?

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I am creating a sample application containing an `Activity` [having `ListView` and `Button`] in layout file. `ListView` is custom containing [Label/Name and CheckBox]. I want to write some code which will change text of the `Button` from adapter class of `ListView` based on List Item `CheckBox` check [T/F].

Comment: @SathishKumarJ How come ADAPTER class will manage it though above method helps to update UI. Because Button instance is in Activity class which I need to handle from adapter class. Please read question carefully.

Comment: I think you can use interfaces. Based on onCheck of checkBox callBack you can change the text..

Comment: @Raghavendra Please read the question carefully & above comment too.

Comment: @VVB he is right i also told you about that solution on your last que

Comment: @VVB Can u clarify me this. U have a button in activity and checkbox in listview i.e., in adapter right. If u check or uncheck you want to change the text of the button which is in activity? Will u pass context to adapter or not?

Comment: @VVB just try my solution hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
     listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
            {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
                {
                    // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                    AppListOfAllApps Selecteditems = (AppListOfAllApps) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    if (view != null)
                    {
                        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                        Selecteditems = (AppListOfAllApps) checkBox.getTag();
                        //here you will get the selected item you may also get the text from it accordingly and then using using button variable just set text
button.settext("whatever");
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Activity :**

```
public class Your_Activity extends Activity implements OnCheckListener// Implement your listener here

@Override
public void OnCheck(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   // notify your activity component here 
}
```

**In Adapter class :**

```
private OnCheckListener listener;

public interface OnCheckListener {
    public void OnCheck(int position);
}

public Your_adapter_constructor(OnCheckListener listener) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.listener = listener;
}

 // On your getView()
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    listener.OnCheck(position);// If you want to pass some value add it here
                }
            });
```

Comment: Tried your  code. Didn't work. It is not just going inside Activity's listener method.